# Hibernate mapping can't find resources

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, mapping

I'm trying to compile my project but the compiler keeps giving the error that he can't find my resource file and so he can't compile

```
    jul 23, 2013 1:29:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: src/main/resources/Movies.hbm.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: src/main/resources/Movies.hbm.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hp.videotheek.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at com.hp.videotheek.App.main(App.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: src/main/resources/Movies.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:738)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2139)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2072)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1987)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1966)
    at com.hp.videotheek.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 1 more
```

hibernate.cfg.xml file, here he can't find the mapping resources but it's on the right place

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="src/main/resources/Movies.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Movies.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.hp.videotheek">
    <class name="Movies" table="movies">
        <id name="movie_id" column="movie_id">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="movie_name" type="string" column="movie_name"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In the screenshot you can see how I have set my mapping and where the files are in my my project

[image]

Comment: just check from where your class path starts, is it src folder? start your mapping resource attribute value from that point.

Comment: no in both casses the compiler can't find the resource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed my own problem instead of giving the hug url I just gave in mapping

```
<mapping resource="Movies.hbm.xml"/>
```

So now he just looks in the same map as the hibernate.cfg.xml file and he will find it immediatly